# Write RegEx to txt file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, typeerror

I am working with the following code to print my output to a txt file using RegEx. However I always get this error message:

```
 File "C:\lib\re.py", line 213, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
```

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
import glob
import os
import re


def extractor():
    os.chdir(r"F:\Test")
    for file in glob.iglob("*.html"):  # iterates over all files in the directory ending in .html
        with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f, open((file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".txt", "w") as out:
            contents = f.read()
            extract = re.compile(r'RegEx', re.I | re.S)
            if re.findall(extract, contents) is not None:
                for x in re.findall(extract, contents):
                    out.write(x)
            out.close()
extractor()
```

Anyone an idea what causes this error? Apparently it has something to do with a type error?

Comment: Use `re.compile(r'RegEx', re.I | re.S)` instead of `re.findall(r'RegEx', re.I | re.S)`. You must have meant to compile the regex before extracting something from the `contents`.

Comment: Still get an error message on my code line "out.write()". TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _sre.SRE_Pattern

Comment: Yes, because now `extract` is a regex object. You need to write the re.findall results there. `for x in re.findall(extract, contents): out.write(x)` or concat the tuple if you have several capturing groups in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my code. However I still get an error message: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple  ,...  this is driving me nuts...

Comment: I believe you should remove `if re.findall(extract, contents) is not None:` completely. Sorry, can't test now.

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't work either. Nevermind....I'll keep on trying to get this working

Answer (score 0):

Slightly adjusted:

```
import glob
import os
import re


def extractor():
    # you only need it once, dont' you?
    extract = re.compile(r'RegEx', re.I | re.S)
    os.chdir(r"F:\Test")
    for file in glob.iglob("*.html"):  # iterates over all files in the directory ending in .html
    with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f, open((file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".txt", "w") as out:
        contents = f.read()
        for match in extract.findall(contents):
            out.write(match)
        out.close()

extractor()
```

This uses `extract` as an object and does not even require the `if not None` check in your loop.
If it is still not working, please elaborate on your actual regular expression (does it have several groups, etc.?).

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately pycharm still gives me an error message: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple. I updated my code, you can see my RegEx, but it should be fine...

Comment: wie kommt man denn in den Chatraum? Dann kann ich dir mal ganz kurz schildern was mein Problem ist ohne hier den Rahmen mit Kommentaren zu sprengen

Comment: was war das denn gerade?

Comment: @FlorianSchramm: Das geht automatisch - einfach ein bisschen ping pong mit den Kommentaren hin und her, dann kommt das automatisch.

Comment: Na dann. Ab gehts